# Pointers in C Programming- Coordinate conversion

Tags: c, pointers

I should write a program to convert Cartesian coordinates to Polar and vice versa with use of pointers, I wrote the following code but my function gives me segmentation fault. I tried to do it without the pointers and still it doesn't send my numbers to the function, can someone help to modify my pointer code? I'm new with C.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

void cart(float *radius,float *degree)
{
    float *x,*y,*radians;
    *radians= (3.14159265359/180) * *degree;
    *x= *radius * cos(*radians); 
    *y= *radius * sin(*radians);
}

int main()
{
    float radius, radians, degree;
    float x,y;
    int M;
    char C,P;
    printf(" Enter C if you are converting Cartesian to Polar \n"); 
    printf(" Enter P if you are converting Polar to Cartesian \n");
    scanf("%c",&M);

    if (M=='P')
    {
        printf("Enter the Radius and Angle separated by comma \n");
        scanf("%f,%f",&radius,&degree);
        cart(&radius,&degree);
        printf("Cartesian form is (%f,%f) \n",x,y);
    }
    else if (M=='C')
    {
        printf("Enter values of X and Y separated by comma \n");
        scanf("%f,%f",&x,&y);
        radius=sqrt(((x*x)+(y*y))); // finding radius 
        radians=atan(y/x); //finding angle in radians
        printf("Polar form is (%f,%f) \n",radius,radians); //angle is in radians
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What do you think this `*y=*radius * sin(*radians);` is doing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first thing to note is in your 'cart' function:

```
void cart(float *radius,float *degree)
{
float *x,*y,*radians;
*radians= (3.14159265359/180) * *degree;
*x= *radius * cos(*radians); 
*y= *radius * sin(*radians);
}
```

You have declared pointers named `x`, `y` and `radians`, but they do not yet point to anything.

So when you 'de-reference' them with `*x`, `*y` and `*radians` you are accessing memory that does not exist, which will result in undefined behavior, possibly a segmentation fault.

I would assume that your goal is to get the `x`, `y` and `radians` from your main function to match up with those, so you should be passing them into the function as well.

Comment: They not necessarily give a segmentation fault, if by change the `x` or `y` are pointing somewhere then something weird will happen, it's called undefined behavior.

Comment: @iharob : 
This is true.  I felt that it was the most likely cause of the segmentation fault however.

Comment: It is, it's just that it's not necessarily a segmentation fault. But in this case that is what's happening.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you mean is this:

```
void cart(float radius, float degree, float *x, float *y)
 {
    float radians;
    if ((x == NULL) || (y == NULL))
        return;
    radians = 3.14159265359 / 180.0 * degree;
    *x      = radius * cos(radians); 
    *y      = radius * sin(radians);
 }
```

and call it like this

```
float x, y, radius, degree;

if (scanf("%f,%f", &radius, &degree) == 2)
    cart(radius, degree, &x, &y);
else
 {
    fprintf(stderr, "error: invalid input expexted <radius,degree>\n");
    exit(1);
 }
```

In your original implementation you were declaring `x` and `y` as pointers but you hadn't initialized them, since you mean to modify them in the function you need to pass pointers which contain the addresses of the variables you wish to modify, for that you use the `&` **address of** operator.

Comment: shouldn't it be `cart(radius, degree, &x, &y)`?